# Can't deploy with debug.keystore from another machine

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play-services, keystore

I've switched from android studio to xamarin for an application (game) I've already configured in google play developer console.  I've copied and pasted the debug.keystore to C:\Users\my profile\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\ and cleaned the solution (I'm on visual studio 2015).  The solution builds fine but the application is never installed to my Genymotion device.  I see the following:

> Android application is debugging. The application could not be
>   started. Ensure that the application has been installed to the target
>   device and has a launchable activity (MainLauncher = true).
>
> Additionally, check Build->Configuration Manager to ensure this
>   project is set to Deploy for this configuration.

When i revert to the old keystore, clean, and build/deploy it works again.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Sometimes when the keystore changes I have to manually uninstall the app through the application manager. Depending on the Android version, it's usually somewhere in Settings -> Applications -> Application Manager -> Find the app, select it, uninstall. For some reason, the usual uninstall or just letting the IDE deploy uninstall causes the app to not launch after the keystore changes. I'm not sure if it will help you, but maybe worth trying if you haven't.

Comment: All I did was the usual uninstall.  I'll try that when I get home.

Comment: Yep.  That worked.  Even though I had uninstalled the app by dragging and dropping it to the trash icon, when I looked in the 'Apps' section of my settings there was still something to be uninstalled.  After that it began deploying with the other keystore.  If you write that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that when the keystore changes, you have to follow a different uninstall process. Try uninstalling the app through the Application Manager. Depending on your version of Android, it's usually somewhere in Settings -> Applications -> Application Manager -> Find the app in the list, select it, uninstall.

For some reason, just using the trash icon to uninstall the app doesn't seem to remove the code signing information. But if you use the Application manager to uninstall, that will remove the code signing information. Then you can build and deploy with a different keystore.